# I created a function that generates a random number which is contained inside the variable. I run the code on the console yet I get undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, var

```
function nextSequence() {
    var randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);
}
```

i ran this on the console yet only got undefined i dont know what is wrong with this. any help is appreciated

Comment: How did you run the code? Did you log the non-existing return value of `nextSequence()` ?

Comment: The function has no `return` statement. Why do you expect it to return the random number?

Comment: i used the console from chrome : console.log(nextSequence());

Comment: And how **exactly** did you run that code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am new in learning JavaScript. Thank you for your time  @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this number outside of the function, you need to return it from the body of the function and then call the function itself:

```js
function nextSequence() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
}

const num = nextSequence();

console.log(num);
```

Comment: BTW, in general you should avoid `var` as there are problems with variable scope https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-let-and-const-keywords-in-javascript/